# Ubuntu + nginx - trying to install GeoIP module

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, geoip

I'm using vagrant (VVV actually) to run local wordpress installs. I want to test different behaviors for different GEO's on my local machine instead of upload it every time to the server which is annoying.

So, I've tried to install the GeoIP nginx module to the local machine with the following guide https://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_166/ (and a bit more google but it doesn't matter at the moment).

When I'm using `./configure` the following is exists:

```
checking for GeoIP library ... found
checking for GeoIP IPv6 support ... found
```

I've also set the .dat files in my conf file, and set the `$_SERVER` (fastcgi_param) parameters - so they displayed when I'm printing the `$_SERVER` var.

But those GeoIP vars are empty. I'm not sure about the reason, but 2 things is bothering me. First, when I'm write `nginx -V` in the terminal the argument `--with-http_geoip_module` is missing. Second, could it actually works if the `REMOTE_ADDR` (IP) is not my real IP? (192.168.1.50 for example).

nginx is a bit strange for me, so sorry if something isn't exact..

--

Operating system - macOS, nginx version - 1.3.15, running with VVV (vagrant box)

Comment: did you run `sudo make install` after `./configure`? And also what is the output of `sudo find / -type f -name "nginx"`?

Comment: Yes, I run this command.

This is the results of what you ask:
`/usr/share/lintian/overrides/nginx
/usr/sbin/nginx
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
/etc/logrotate.d/nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx
/etc/default/nginx`

Comment: Try if `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V` or `/usr/share/lintian/overrides/nginx -V` see if any of those help

Comment: recompile nginx `--with-http_geoip_module`

Comment: @TarunLalwani `sbin/nginx` returns `nginx version: nginx/1.13.5
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
configure arguments: --with-http_geoip_module`

Comment: So problem solved?

Comment: Not sure, maybe I didn't understand something.. I've found this thing with specific location of `nginx`. But if I try the same thing from the root folder - the module is missing. In addition, the vars in the PHP are empty.. so it doesn't seems like something is actually works..

Answer (score 0):

If there is a reverse proxy in front of your nginx, use [`geoip_proxy`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html#geoip_proxy) to set IPs whose X-Forwarded-For-Header can be trusted.

You can also use that without actually having a reverse proxy when you're developing. Add your local IP to the geoip_proxy-list and set the `X-Forwarded-For`-Header to your public IP in your browser (use a plugin like Modify Headers).